# Does this belong on Super User?

Tags: support, flagging

I'm seeing a lot of questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402384/plesk-domain-namserver-setup) flagged as belonging on Server Fault.

The SF FAQ says quite emphatically that their site is for **professional** server admins only, so it probably doesn't belong there.

Is this an appropriate question for Super User?

Comment: Should we move this to the SF meta so the community there can answer?

Comment: @Bill - if anything, maybe the SuperUser meta, based on Jacob's answer.  I think he's right that it definitely doesn't belong on SF; I'm not sure if it belongs on SU or not

Comment: Okay, do you want to edit it up to target SU before I migrate?

Comment: @Bill - edited.  Feel free to edit over me if anything should be clearer.

Comment: Does it belong *anywhere* on SE? I doubt that.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

Domain nameserver setup is not really in the scope of Super User. This sounds more like a question for [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), as he's trying to set up his VPS and domain information, but isn't really doing server management.

Answer (score 2):

The Server Fault FAQ says pretty clearly that they don't want questions about home networking or running a server at home, which I think this qualifies as.  Such questions certainly don't belong on SO.  I'd say that Super User is actually the best place.